# Does Visual Studio 2017 have a specific keyboard combination for create single-line comments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comments

I have a question. When I work in IntelliJ IDEA, I use the combination Ctrl + / for creating single-line comments. At now, I work in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and I see only one combination (Ctrl + K + C), but it creates multi-line comment. For example:

(I want to get it)

```
//InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &ACustomPlayerController::MoveForward);
//InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &ACustomPlayerController::MoveRight);
//InputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &ACustomPlayerController::Turn);
```

But when I select these lines and press "Ctrl + K + C" I get such that:

```
InputComponent->Bi/*ndAxis("MoveForward", this, &ACustomPlayerController::MoveForward);
InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &ACustomPlayerController::MoveRight);
InputComponent->Bind*/Axis("Turn", this, &ACustomPlayerController::Turn);
```

Does MVS 2017 have a specific combination for creating single-line comments?
I'm programming in C++.
Thx!

Comment: There is only one command to comment selection. So (unless added by an extension) there is only one option. How it is used depends on the language (eg. C# you get line comments)

Comment: @Richard Ok! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not select whole lines, you will get `/* ... */` comments. If you select whole lines, you will get `//` style comment.

Also try using "`CTRL + K + C`" without any selection and you should get the current line commented out with `//` style as in your example.

Otherwise look up the current key assignment for comments in Visual Studio. Go to "Tools > Options", Navigate to "Environment > Keyboard" and look up the shortcut for "Edit.CommentSelection".